# Retrieving data from an Excel file in Django using Pandas: How can I include duplicates that are being overwritten by Python?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am creating a Django application which retrieves data from an excel file.
[The excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z7Q6.png)

I access the excel file through the scrape.py file:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
DATA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Data")

database_path = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "Data.xlsx")
Database = pd.read_excel(database_path)

Then I have this class:

class skimask:
    def __init__(self, name, GradesWDates, motive, avgGrade, highestgrade, pfp, nexttest, recentgrades, tens):
        self.name = name
        self.GradesWDates = GradesWDates
        self.motive = motive
        self.avgGrade = avgGrade
        self.highestgrade = highestgrade
        self.pfp = pfp
        self.nexttest = nexttest
        self.recentgrades = recentgrades
        self.tens = tens
        self.subjects = {}

Evan = skimask('Evan', dict(zip(Database.Evan, Database.Date)), "B", 0, 0, "./static/media/evan1.png", list(Database.EvanNext), [], 0)
Felix = skimask('Felix', dict(zip(Database.Felix, Database.Date)), "B+", 0, 0, "./static/media/felix.png", list(Database.FelixNext), [], 0)
Hessel = skimask('Hessel', dict(zip(Database.Hessel, Database.Date)), "A+", 0, 0, "./static/media/hessel2.png", list(Database.HesselNext), [], 0)
Niels = skimask('Niels', dict(zip(Database.Niels, Database.Date)), "B", 0, 0, "./static/media/niels.png", list(Database.NielsNext), [], 0)
Sem = skimask('Sem', dict(zip(Database.Sem, Database.Date)), "A", 0, 0, "./static/media/sem1.png", list(Database.SemNext), [], 0)
Students = [Evan, Felix, Hessel, Niels, Sem]
```

This excel file is a file of all our grades of this year, and coincidentally there are duplicates, of course. But Python, for some reason, overwrites duplicates and skips over them. But I want to include those duplicates. How am I able to also include those duplicates?

I tried zipping the dictionary with 2 lists thinking Python wouldn't overwrite the duplicates, but for some reason Python still overwrites my duplicates.

Comment: It would be helpful either to provide a specimen Excel file, or debug where the duplicates are erased. Is it in `pd.read_excel()` (I guess not here), or in the class?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

I forgot that dictionaries did not allow duplicates as data model, so instead I have converted the dictionaries to lists that do allow duplicates.